# Are the exercises about finding domain of functions ill-posed questions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

In the definition of a function, we need to specify its domain and codomain. But now I'm puzzled by the fact that many  exercises will state: Find the domain of the function [insert random function here]. But those are not functions since their domain is not specified. How can we modify the exercises so that they actually make sense?

Comment: These questions can be re-worded to make them precise. Example: Find the largest subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ such that there exists a function $f: A \to \mathbb R$ with $f(x)=\frac 1  x$ for all $x \in A$.

Comment: You are right, they are ill posed. They should be posed as @KaviRamaMurthy did  it. I don't know why there are instructors that  prefer to pose it wrong.

Comment: I agree that questions like this are not really very rigorous. With examples like $x/x$ or $(x - x)/x$, there isn't really enough information to give a precise answer.

Comment: Everyone understand that it means:   find the maximal subset of $\mathbf R$ on which  this formula (or these formulæ) is (are) defined. It is simply an elliptic question (in the rhetorical sense).